# How to calculate grades using random number generator?

Tags: java

I am currently re-working on a problem which I missed on my quiz that asked me to define and use constructors for Student class, instead of using default constructors. And in GradeCalculator class, I will need to generate the midterm and final grades using the random number generator. I have looked at the similar examples provided by the book, but I still could not figure out why my program keeps getting errors. Can someone give me some hints or point me to right direction? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
public class Student {
private int midterm;
private int finalExam;

public double getMidterm()
{
return midterm;
}
public double getFinalExam()
{
return finalExam;
}
public double getFinalGrade()
{
return midterm * 0.35 + finalExam * 0.65;
}

public void showGrades()
{
System.out.print("Student : ");
System.out.printf(", Midterm is: %.2f. Final Exam is: %.2f. Final Grade is: %.2f \n",    midterm, finalExam, getFinalGrade());
}

}

import java.util.Random;

public class GradeCalculator {
public static void main(String[] args)
{

int sum;
Student[] studentArray = new Student[3];

for (int index = 0; index < studentArray.length; index++)
{
Student s = new Student();

System.out.print("Student" + (index+1) + ": " );
Random midterm = new Random();
System.out.print(", Midterm is: " + midterm.nextInt(100));
Random finalExam = new Random();
System.out.print(", Final exam is: " + finalExam.nextInt(100));
sum = midterm + finalExam;
System.out.println(", Final Grade is: " + sum);

studentArray[index] = s;

}

for(int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++)
{
Student s = studentArray[i];
s.showGrades(); 
}

double sum = 0.0;
double averageGrade;
for(int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++)
{
double finalGrades = studentArray[i].getFinalGrade();
sum = sum + finalGrades;
}
averageGrade = sum / studentArray.length; 
System.out.printf("The average final grade is: %.2f", averageGrade);

}
}
```

here's the actual question:

1. Student class
     Attributes 
   Create a Student class with 2 attributes(instance variables), including
   ◦     midterm (int)
   ◦     finalExam (int)

   Methods
   Define getters for each attribute. Therefore, you have to create 2 getters in total.
   Define a method, getFinalGrade, which calculates the final grade according to the following grading scheme. After the computation, return the result of final grade.
   ◦     Grading:
   ▪     Midterm:        35%
   ▪     Final exam:    65%
   Define a method, showGrades, which outputs the details of attributes. The grades should be displayed as a number with two decimal places only. (See the example)
   ◦     Output example: “Student[1], Midterm: 90.00, Final Exam: 80.00, Final Grade: 82.00”
2. GradeCalculator class
   Create a GradeCalculator class and put everything (Step 1 to Step 4 below) in the main method.
   Step 1: create a Student array, called studentArray, whose length is 3.
   Step 2: create 3 Student objects by using loop. Use random number generator to generate a number from 0 to 100 (both 0 and 100 inclusive) to generate a midterm grade and finalExam grade for the student. Store these in corresponding attributes. After all values are set, store the newly-created Student object to studentArray.
   Step 3: loop studentArray to print out the details of each student by calling showGrades.
   Step 4: calculate the average final grade of these 3 student and print it out on the screen. The grades should be displayed as a number with two decimal places only.
   Output example: “The average final grade is: 85.35”

Comment: Don't copy-paste your homework questions here. Attempt a solution and if you get stuck on a line or two, ask here. The best thing for both you and us is for you to do your own homework.

Answer (score 1):

What the question is asking for is the ability to write code that looks like

```
Student s = new Student(midTermScore, finalExamScore);
```

You accomplish this by writing constructors that initialises the object, here `s`, with the given values.

The oracle website does a decent job at explaining the concepts. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html